# Inserting new password by overriding old password

Tags: yii, passwords

In yii i am creating project. After validation of user's entered email, i am displaying password.php file which is having textfield for entering new password.
Password.php=

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'email-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
   ));
        echo CHtml::textField('Enter new password');
        echo CHtml::textField('Repeat password');
        echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
        $this->endWidget();
```

When user will enter new password and click on submit button i want to insert this new password into User table's password field, in such a way that it overright old password.

In controller i had created method as-

```
public function actionCreate(){

if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {

 $record=User2::model()->find(array(
'select'=>'userId, securityQuestionId, primaryEmail',
'condition'=>'primaryEmail=:email',
'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
);

if($record===null) {
                  echo "Email invalid";
                   }

else {
    echo "email exists";


      $this->render('Password');
      if(isset($_POST['Password']))
        {

        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
        $command->insert('User', array(
                    'password'=>$_POST['password'] ,
                    //'params'=>array(':password'=>$_POST['password'])

        }          



 }

    }
    else{
        $this->render('emailForm'); //show the view with the password field
    }
```

But its not inserting new password. So How can i implement this...Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get password like this `$_POST['Password']`, because you haven't set this post variable.

You had to use:

```
echo CHtml::textField('password');
echo CHtml::textField('repeatPassword');
echo CHtml::hiddenField('email', $email);
```

'password' and 'repeatPassword' are names of POST vars

And in your controller you have too many mistakes, try this (check for typos):

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
 $record=User2::model()->find(array(
'select'=>'userId, securityQuestionId, primaryEmail',
'condition'=>'primaryEmail=:email',
'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
);

if($record===null) {
                  echo "Email invalid";
                   }

else {
    if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['repeatPassword']) && ($_POST['password'] === $_POST['repeatPassword']))
    {
        $record->password = $_POST['password'];
        if ($record->save()) {
             $this->render('saved');
        }
    }          

    $this->render('Password' array('email'=>$_POST['email']));
}

 }

    }
    else{
        $this->render('emailForm'); //show the view with the password field
    }
```

In your code `if(isset($_POST['Password']))` won't ever execute, because after sending password you haven't set `email` variable. So you just `$this->render('emailForm');`. Thus we set it by `CHtml::hiddenField('email', $email);`

**Upd.** I strongly recommend you to read [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/). It will save a lot of time for you.

Comment: thanx sir for helping me.I have made changes as per you had told. but it is not inserting new password into table.

Comment: Sir what changes i need to do for inserting user's new entered password into User tables passowrd filed. i.e. for overriding existing old password by this new password field

Comment: Debug your code, I can't guess what is wrong. you need to execute `$record->password = $_POST['password'];
        if ($record->save()) {
             $this->render('saved');
        }`
so add before this `var_dump($_POST['password'])` and see is it working after sending newPassword. If not try to debug other variables and figure out why not.

Comment: Sir its working. If i want to send this change password functionality as link to email address what i should need to do.

Comment: You need to write other action. Briefly: add secure code table (user_id, code). When user click "forgot pass" - generate the code, save it into DB and send to user link "/index.php?r=User/changePass&code=yourCode". In your changePass action get user_id with the code and if OK - show form with new pass....then you  know

Answer (score 1):

First of all the way you are handling the form is certainly not Yii-ish which means it's not really the way to go.

The way you should handle this is by creating an object which extends from the [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) and put all your logic code in there instead of in the controller.

Now, if you want to continue working with your piece of code, then it would be best to place the following piece of code

```
$this->render('Password');
```

**BELOW** the if isset password stuff.

For your problem, the reason why your password isn't being updated is because the query you created is not being executed. If we take a look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#executing-sql-statements) then we can see that the following piece of code should be added:

```
$command->execute();
```

Which will execute your piece of sql.

Comment: this changes won't help. Because code in `if(isset($_POST['Password']))` won't ever execute, and `$command->insert(...` isn't right

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
$user = User::find('email = :email', ':email' => $_POST['email']);

if( empty($user) )
  return;

$user->password = $_POST['password'];
$user->save();
```