# In yii how to insert record in table by overriding existing entry

Tags: insert, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In yii how to insert new password by overriding old password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620878/in-yii-how-to-insert-new-password-by-overriding-old-password)

I am very new to using the Yii framework.

I am creating a password recreation function in Yii. If email id is existing then the password.php page will be displayed to that user requesting to enter a new password.

Suppose that this is my view file

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'email-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
));

        echo CHtml::textField('password');
        echo CHtml::textField('repeatPassword');
        echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
        $this->endWidget();`
```

Now the user will need to enter a new password. I want to put this newly entered password in the database in the User table it's password field by overriding the old password. But I have no idea on how to achieve that.

Any tips?

Comment: Similar question has been asked couple of hours ago => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620878/in-yii-how-to-insert-new-password-by-overrighting-old-password